# Lubuntu: apt-get gives errors such as "keysafe: package not found"?

Tags: installation, command-line, apt

When I install a program in terminal with apt-get or apt-fast I get messages like these:

```
keysafe: package not found
genesis: package not found
xdx: package not found
omaque: package not found
live-magic: package not found
wesnoth-1.8: package not found
galan: package not found
qgis: package not found
pino: package not found
easydiff.app: package not found
scenic: package not found
mined: package not found
jlgui: package not found
seamonkey: package not found
gmameui: package not found
qtodo: package not found
aee: package not found
gtkwhiteboard: package not found
pouetchess: package not found
streamtuner: package not found
jcgui: package not found
```

The installation is otherwise ok, but is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [known problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2039604) and an [unconfirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lubuntu-software-center/+bug/1000698) caused by something in the Lubuntu Software Center (LSC) database, and possibly a conflict between LSC and USC if installed.

You can try to fix it by removing LSC and reinstalling it to recreate the database (you will get a warning about removing `lubuntu-desktop` but don't worry, nothing but LSC will be removed):

```
sudo apt-get purge lubuntu-software-center
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center
sudo apt-get update
```

And if that doesn't work **and** you have Ubuntu Software Center installed:

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center
sudo apt-get update
```